# Compare string value to datagridview row 0 in any cell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I cannot find anything when I search for this question because I don't really know how to word it.

I have a dataGridView that is getting values from an excel file. That works fine, but I want to compare all the values in row 0 with a string value.

Here is the code I have

```
string mat = "test";
if(mat == dataGridView1[0,0].Value.ToString())
        {
            tst.Text = dataGridView1[1,0].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Which only works for the cells in the first entry. I need to scan all values. I would think it would be something like:

```
string mat = "test";
int x = ???;
if(mat == dataGridView1[0,x].Value.ToString())
        {
            tst.Text = dataGridView1[1,x].Value.ToString();
        }
```

This is driving me insane because it is such a simple thing that I know has to be possible. Otherwise I'm going to have to copy and paste with x equal to 1,2,3, etc. for however many values the sheet has.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put you verrification in a loop

```
string mat = "test";
for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;i++){
        if(dataGridView1[0,i].Value != null && mat == dataGridView1[0,i].Value.ToString())
        {
            tst.Text = dataGridView1[1,i].Value.ToString();
        }
}
```

i STRONGLY remcommend that you read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: why is your loop going until i<10?

Comment: i just took a random number

Comment: Why not using the actual variable (number of columns/cells)?

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count

Comment: @ varocarbas missed that, sorry

Comment: No problem, here to help. Perhaps you should test the codes before posting them. This was a specific question about DataGridView and you gave a generic answer which does not address all the issues (like null cells; take a look at Andrew's sample).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so freaking much. I knew it had to involve some kind of loop. Now with the cell count I don't have to worry about how much data is in the xls. Thank you both very very much. I feel sane again.

Comment: You have to account for nulls. Otherwise your code can crash. You have to add dataGridView1[0,i].Value != null as a higher-level condition or inside the current condition at the start and linked with &&

Comment: Actually one slight error in that addition. Rows[0].Cells.Count counts how many cells are in each row. What is really needed for this instance is how many rows there are. So I just did dataGridView1.RowCount

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dataGridView1 != null)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.Equals("test"))
        {
            tst.Text = cell.Value;
        }
    }
}
```